USB Connection to reset of iOS Devices
I am trying to record the screen of an ios_device using facebook/idb and able to record the screen but after multiple recordings, the recording stops. the reason for this is that the ios_device is not sending the video for some reason.
Replugging the usb seems to work so I've tried emulating it with code. but it fails on deviceRequest with error (iokit/usb) pipe has stalled, error needs to be cleared, can someone help me with what is wrong?


    result = (*iodev)->QueryInterface(
        iodev, CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes(kIOUSBDeviceInterfaceID245), (LPVOID)&dev);
    IODestroyPlugInInterface(iodev);
    if (result || !dev) {
      fprintf(stderr, "could not get device interface: %08x\n", (int)result);
      continue;
    }
 
    // get device data
    IOReturn err = (*dev)->USBGetSerialNumberStringIndex(dev, &serial_index);
    if (err != kIOReturnSuccess) {
      printf("Could not get serial number string index (error: %x)\n", err);
      return;
    }
    request.bmRequestType =
        USBmakebmRequestType(kUSBIn, kUSBStandard, kUSBDevice);
    request.bRequest = kUSBRqGetDescriptor;
    request.wValue = (kUSBStringDesc << 8) | serial_index;
    request.wIndex = 0x409; // english
    request.wLength = sizeof(buffer);
    request.pData = &buffer[0];
    bzero(&buffer[0], sizeof(buffer));
    err = (*dev)->DeviceRequest(dev, &request);
    if (err != kIOReturnSuccess) {
      char *err_str = mach_error_string(err);
      printf("Could not request usb device %s\n", err_str);
      // the request failed.
      return;
    }




If a pipe is stalled, have you tried clearing the stall with ClearPipeStallBothEnds()? (Note that this is a method on the USB interface, not the parent device.) If that doesn't help, what are you using to reset the device? USBDeviceReEnumerate should be equivalent to a hard re-plug, but that does also mean your device handles will all become invalid and you need to re-match and query the device from scratch.

will it work in 2.4.5 version of USB ?
